# JAXB marshalling to a StringWriter: Is it necassary to declare the string encoding (e.g. UTF-8)?

Tags: java, jaxb

With this code:

```
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( aObj.getClass());
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal( aObj, sw);
        return sw.toString();
```

I am serializing a JAXB object directly into a StringWriter: My examples show that two byte UTF-8 characters like 'ü' are serialized perfectly, i.e. they are contained as expected in the resulting java string. Later, when sending over a socket, the resulting java string is serialized as aXml.getBytes( "UTF-8").

Can it be dangerous if the above marshaller does not declare the UTF-8 character encoding explicitely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not dangerous.

> By default, the Marshaller will use UTF-8 encoding when generating XML
>   data to a java.io.OutputStream, or a java.io.Writer. Use the
>   setProperty API to change the output encoding used during these
>   marshal operations. Client applications are expected to supply a valid
>   character encoding name as defined in the W3C XML 1.0 Recommendation
>   and supported by your Java Platform.

`jaxb.encoding` - value must be a java.lang.String
The output encoding to use when marshalling the XML data. The Marshaller will use "UTF-8" by default if this property is not specified.

[Reference here](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html)

Comment: Thanks for your insights. My question indeed was more: Does the character encoding at all play a role if the target is a StringWriter (which operates per definition on characters and not on bytes)?